# Turn row values from multiple columns into column names in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
   state1     state1_pp     state2     state2_pp    state3   state3_pp
   <chr>      <chr>         <chr>      <chr>         <chr>   <chr>  
 1 0          0.995614      F          0.004386      NA      0  
 2 0          1             NA         0             NA      0  
 3 0          1             NA         0             NA      0
```

I want the values from each of the rows to be the column names the numeric values to be the row values:

```
   0             F             NA   
   <chr>         <chr>         <chr>     
 1 0.995614      0.004386      0        
 2 1             0             0        
 3 1             0             0
```

How do I do this in R?

Or a more complex scenario:

```
  state1     state1_pp     state2     state2_pp    state3   state3_pp
 1 0          0.995614      F          0.004386      NA      0  
 2 A          1             B          0             C       0  
 3 D          0.7           B          0.3           NA      0
```

This is what I want:

```
   0          A     D     F          B   C   NA
 1 0.995614   0     0     0.004386   0   0   0 
 2 0          1     0     0          0   0   0 
 3 0          0     0.7   0         0.3  0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt using `dplyr` and `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  mutate(name = sub('\\d+', '', name)) %>%
  group_by(name, row) %>%
  mutate(row1 = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  group_by(state, row) %>%
  mutate(row1 = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = state, values_from = state_pp, 
              values_fill = list(state_pp = 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row, -row1)


# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  `0`      F        `NA`  A     B     C     D    
#  <chr>    <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 0.995614 0.004386 0     0     0     0     0    
#2 0        0        0     1     0     0     0    
#3 0        0        0     0     0.3   0     0.7
```

Answer (score 1):

First a warning, having column names that are numeric (like `1`) or are reserved R keywords (like `NA`) can cause you all sorts of errors. But if you must do it, I suggest the following:

```r
library(dplyr)

# extract title row
headers <- df %>%
  head(1) %>%
  select(state1, state2, state3) %>%
  unlist(use.names = FALSE) %>%
  as.character()
# replace NA with "NA"
headers[is.na(headers)] = "NA"

# drop columns that are not wanted
new_df <- df %>%
  select(-state1, -state2, -state3)
# replace column names
colnames(new_df) <- headers
```

In order to refer to your new columns you will probably need to use backticks: `` ` ``

So with your new column names `0`, `F` and `NA` you can call `df$F` but you can not call `df$NA` or `df$1`. Instead you will have to call `` df$`1` `` and `` df$`NA` ``.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Could you also tell me how I deal with situations in which there are more than states? I edited my question to include an example.